# Global sections of a vector bundle on the projective space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-space

This comes from a problem I'm working on, but I would like to phrase it in generality.

I consider a vector bundle $E$ on the complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$. Is there some criterion to decide whether $E$ admits a global section or not, for example by looking at chern classes of $E$, or the determinant of $E$...

For sure it's easy to answer when the vector bundle splits, $E=\oplus_i \mathcal{O}(d_i)$, and I know the $d_i$'s, but I'm unable to find an analogy for a non-splitting vector bundle. Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch may help, that's why I'm thinking about chern classes: if $\chi(E)$ is positive, I know that either $E$ or $(E^*\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-3))$ is effective, but then I don't know how I can choose which one is effective.

On $\mathbb{P}^1$ everything is easy, since any vector bundle splits on it, but this is already not true for the projective plane. Maybe some classification result could help?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're trying to answer the question in general (as opposed to for a particular bundle with a concrete presentation of some sort) it's probably quite hard. You might want to look at papers of Izzet Coskun (particularly in collaboration with Jack Huizenga) with titles that mention the projective plane, rational surfaces, and/or Brill-Noether theory.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I didn't know it,.. but is it "WEAK BRILL-NOETHER FOR RATIONAL SURFACES"? 
I have indeed a description of my vector bundle. But I think I proved that it cannot be semistable - which is quite annoying.